# Bootstrap 3 scrollable div for table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 3 with a navbar at the top and a page that displays a table formatted using Bootstrap 3's table class.  I would like the table (which is sitting in its own div) to be the only part of the page that is scrollable (when the width/height of the data in the table exceeds that of the page).  I have styled the div for the table as follows:

```
.mygrid-wrapper-div {
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 200px;
}
```

I have a fiddle illustrating this, and I added an ugly 5px red border around the div to highlight the area that I would like to have scrollable:

http://jsfiddle.net/4NB2N/4/

Notice that scrolling left-to-right works great - I didn't have to do anything to get this to work, and the div adjusts the scrollbar automatically when the window is resized too.  However, I don't know how to setup the div's height to behave the same way - I hardcoded the 200px value but really I would like the div to fill the "rest" of the window so that when the browser is resized it still works.

How can I make the div behave the same both horizontally and vertically?

Comment: have you tried with a maxheight?

Answer (score 129):

A scrolling comes from a box with class `pre-scrollable`

```
<div class="pre-scrollable"></div>
```

There's more examples: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#code-block 
Wish it helps.

Comment: This works for me e.g. <div class="well well-sm pre-scrollable">
    <samp id="containerLog" class=""></samp>
</div>

Comment: that's super and best solution with this class even in fixed-top or fixed-bottom elements!

Answer (score 25):

Well one way to do it is set the height of your body to the `height` that you want your `page` to be.  In this example I did `600px`.

Then set your `wrapper` height to a percentage of the body here I did `70%` This will adjust your table so that it does not fill up the whole screen but in stead just takes up a percentage of the specified page height.

```
body {
   padding-top: 70px;
   border:1px solid black;
   height:600px;
}

.mygrid-wrapper-div {
   border: solid red 5px;
   overflow: scroll;
   height: 70%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4NB2N/7/

**Update** How about a jQuery approach.

```
$(function() {  
   var window_height = $(window).height(),
   content_height = window_height - 200;
   $('.mygrid-wrapper-div').height(content_height);
});

$( window ).resize(function() {
   var window_height = $(window).height(),
   content_height = window_height - 200;
   $('.mygrid-wrapper-div').height(content_height);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4NB2N/11/

Comment: But I don't know the height of the body/page, the user can resize the browser window to any width/height they choose.  I really just want that <mygrid-wrapper-div> to take up the "rest" of the page.

Comment: Thank you for your help!  However, is there any way to do this without knowing the 200px value for the height?  I was using that as a hardcoded value to show what I'm trying to achieve, but I'd like a more generalized solution so tell the DIV take up the "rest" of the viewable window area?  The window will change height/width as the user resizes it (or uses a device with a different resolution).

Comment: @DavidMcClelland the `200` value is just needed to adjust the height of your wrapper so it does not reach the bottom of the page.  It's not related to your example.  If it reaches the bottom of the page the scroll no longer works like you desire.  Have you tried it on your page?  I think it should work well on most devices..  There may be a chance it does not work on a very small devices such as cell phones.. In which case you can check the `$(window).width()` for a small width and adjust it higher.  Change it to `250` instead of `200` etc..

Answer (score 2):

You can use too

```
style="overflow-y: scroll; height:150px; width: auto;"
```

It's works for me